# How to user NextJs for extract Icy Metadata in stream of audio

Tags: javascript, next.js, metadata

I'm using NextJs 13 with Typescript. I need to extract the title from audio stream. I would like to know how to do this. I know there are packages like “Icy Metadata”, but I don't know how to use it. I am new in Front-End. Can someone help me? The link of WebRadio is this: https://servidor18.brlogic.com:7436/live?type=.m3u